# Node.js best socket.io practice (request-response vs broadcast)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io

I am new to node.js/socket.io and may not be asking this the right way or even asking the right question.

The goal of my app is to get data from an API convert it to a JSON Object and store it in a mongodb.  Then serve the client side the data when needed.  I have thought about two possibilities and was wondering what the best practice would be.  My first notion was to broadcast all of the entries in the database every so often to all of the connections.  The other idea was to have the client request to server what data it needed and then send the requested data to client.

The data being stored in the database is around 100 entries.  The data would be updated from the API approximately every 30 seconds.  If method 1 was chosen the data would be broadcast every 5-10 seconds.  If method 2 was chosen then the data would be sent when requested.  The client side will have different situations where not all data will be needed all the time.  The client side will have to request data every so often to make sure the data is "fresh".

So my question is what is the best practice broadcast a large chunk every x seconds or broadcast smaller chunks when requested.

Sorry if this doesn't make sense.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: I would recommend looking at [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/)'s pub/sub system and their [DDP protocol](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/livedata/DDP.md). The idea is that the server publishes certain data, and then the client subscribes to some of that data. The server sends the client the data it needs, and updates are sent only when changes actually occur.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will check it out. The whole system seems a bit heavy but implementing the DDP protocol is very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

DDP protocol is definitely an interesting way to go, but it might be overkill. Simpler solution is to take the best from both method 1 and 2. If latency is not so important and you have spare bandwidth you can broadcast a "update" message to all clients when new data arrives. The client considers if the update affects it and downloads data it needs.

Slightly more complicated and more effective approach is subscription procedure very similar to DDP. For smaller projects you can implement it yourself in a while. This is how it could work:

- Client subscribes to a chunk of data.
- Server sends this chunk to the client and remembers which clients subscribed to what.
- If the chunk is updated the server goes through the subscription list and sends the new data to subscribers.
- Client can unsubscribe at any time by sending a special message, disconnecting (or optionally by subscribing to different chunk).

By chunk I mean any way how to identify some data. It can be record ID, time range a filter or anything that makes sense in your project.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I am thinking about using 'rooms' implementation to distinguish which users get what. Do you know if this is a good way of storing clients to get certain data?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what rooms implementation is about.